# Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Okay, let me start by saying I am a noob at this. I'm following [this step-by-step video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iyr9WIyxlJc&feature=youtu.be&fbclid=IwAR0tWtQTf9y1Th5_6W7djppHFTUArJiyibWk5a0sUFdokl340B1pRUzi1lc), and I still found a way to mess it up somehow. I've tried reading related questions, but I don't really know much about VBA to make sense of the answers.

Basically, I'm trying (and failing) to create an "Employee Manager." At around 9:44 of the video, the narrator said we'll need to create a macro to hide and show specific cells depending on what tab we click on.

Here is my code for Sheet1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E4:H4")) Is Nothing Then
       Range("B2").Value = Target.Column
       Range("F2").Select
       SwitchHTabs
    End If
End Sub
```

And I have this code under modules, with the macro named SwitchHTabs:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SwitchHTabs()
    Dim SelCol As Long
    Dim FirstRow As Long

    SelCol = ActiveCell.Column

    With Sheet1
        .Range("5:84").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        FirstRow = 5 + ((SelCol - 5) * 20)
        .Range(FirstRow & "." & FirstRow + 19).EntireRow.Hidden = False 'This is the line with the error
    End With
End Sub
```

This error pops up when I try to run the code:
[image]

And when I click Debug, it highlights this line of code:
[image]

Where'd I mess up? I'm using Excel 2016.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare your two `Range` lines in that sub:

```
.Range("5:84").EntireRow.Hidden = True 'Works
.Range(FirstRow & "." & FirstRow + 19).EntireRow.Hidden = False 'Doesn't Work
```

For the sake of argument, let's assume that `FirstRow` is 1, and then process that second line of code:

```
.Range("5:84").EntireRow.Hidden = True 'Works
.Range("1.20").EntireRow.Hidden = False 'Doesn't Work
```

Hopefully it is now easier to see that you have used a Full-Stop in place of a Colon.

(As an aside - you can use `.Rows("5:84").Hidden` instead to remove the need for `.EntireRow`)

Comment: O. M. F. G. I can't believe I missed that, you're a lifesaver! Thank you, thank you, thank you!!!

Answer (score -1):

.Range("C;BE").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
.Range("C;BE").Columns.Hidden = True
both not working

Comment: method 'Range' of object '_worksheet' failed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).